# How to render HTML in a pre tag in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pre

In an [ASP Classic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) (aspx) web form, I could render the whole HTML in a PRE tag like this:

Webpage:

```
<pre><asp:label id="ContentBox" runat="server"></asp:label></pre>
```

[Code-behind](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/code-behind):

```
ContentBox.Text = html string;
```

Then the whole HTML is rendered on the webpage correctly.

I am wondering how I could do the same thing in an ASP.NET MVC [Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine) view. For now, what I see is a raw HTML string.

The HTML string could be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A title</title>
    <style>
          .td_header {background-color: white; text-align:left}
          .table_header {background-color: white; width: 100%}
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="table_header" frame="void">
      <tr>
        <td class="td_header">
          <img src="logo_v3.jpg" alt="Helping" width="261" height="50" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: submit your code and then we can tell. we dont know what are you dong actually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<pre>@Html.Raw(Model.HtmlString)</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works mostly. I just need to fix some small things. This is definitely the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
<pre>
 @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ContentBox)
<pre>
```

This assumes you have a contentbox property in your model

And this will output something like

```
<pre>
 <label> blah blah </label>
<pre>
```

But I think you're thinking that you need asp controls to present data...not so.

In your controllers action method stuff your content into a view bag

```
@ViewBag.ContentBox ="Hello World";
```

On your view use it.

```
<pre>
     @ViewBag.ContentBox
<pre>
```

Should render as you are expecting.

If you are presenting HTML you need to wrap it in @html.raw()